# Add multiple values to dynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to add multiple values to DynamoDB. I want to add all the sets of data.

For example, If 4 values, then 4 rows I want to add in DynamoDB. For 'n' number of receiving values, 'n' rows of them should be added.

I looped through arrays but still only latest data is set into *item* and I am able to save only one row. i.e., the last value of every arrays.

How can I achieve this. Please help me.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/receiveRequests", method=RequestMethod.POST,produces={"application/json"})
public Map<String, Object> receiveRequests(@RequestParam(value="user_id") String user_id,
                                            @RequestParam(value="device_model") String device_model, 
                                            @RequestParam(value="api_key") String api_key,
                                            @RequestParam(value="score") int[] score,
                                            @RequestParam(value="registrationId") String registrationId,
                                            @RequestParam(value="userLocalTime") String[] userLocalTime,
                                            @RequestParam(value="lat") double[] lat,
                                            @RequestParam(value="lon") double[] lon,
                                            @RequestParam(value="accuracy") float[] accuracy,
                                            @RequestParam(value="userTimezone") String userTimezone,
                                            Model model)
{
            try
            {
                AmazonDynamoDBClient client = DynamoDBConfig.getAmazonDBClient();
                DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

                slf4jLogger.info("======================Begin Saving values to DynamoDB===================================================");   
                ScoreTable item = new ScoreTable();
                for(int ScoreValue : score)
                {
                    item.setScore(ScoreValue);
                    slf4jLogger.info("Saving Score: "+ScoreValue);
                }
                item.setDevice_model(device_model);
                slf4jLogger.info("Saving device_model: "+device_model);
                item.setApi_key(api_key);
                slf4jLogger.info("Saving api_key: "+api_key);
                item.setUser_id(user_id);
                slf4jLogger.info("Saving user_id: "+user_id);
                item.setRegistrationId(registrationId);
                slf4jLogger.info("Saving registrationId: "+registrationId);
                for(double latitude : lat)
                {
                    item.setLat(latitude);
                    slf4jLogger.info("Saving latitude: "+latitude);
                }
                for(double longitude : lon)
                {
                    item.setLon(longitude);
                    slf4jLogger.info("Saving longitude: "+longitude);
                }
                for(float accuracyValue : accuracy)
                {
                    item.setAccuracy(accuracyValue);
                    slf4jLogger.info("Saving accuracyValue: "+accuracyValue);
                }
                for(String userlocaltym:userLocalTime)
                {
                    item.setUserLocalTime(userlocaltym);
                    slf4jLogger.info("Saving userlocaltym: "+userlocaltym);
                }
                item.setUserTimezone(userTimezone);
                slf4jLogger.info("Saving userTimezone"+userTimezone);
                mapper.save(item);
                slf4jLogger.info("StressScore Table items: "+item);
            }           
            catch(AmazonServiceException ase)
            {
                //ase.printStackTrace();
                slf4jLogger.error(ase);
                slf4jLogger.error(ase.getMessage());
                slf4jLogger.error(ase.getStackTrace());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                slf4jLogger.error(e);
                slf4jLogger.error(e.getMessage());
                slf4jLogger.error(e.getStackTrace());
            }
 }
```

Here is my Logger:

```
 ======================Begin Saving values to DynamoDB===================================================
Saving Score: 86
Saving Score: 92
Saving Score: 32
Saving Score: 65

Saving device_model: Nexus S
Saving api_key: testApp
Saving user_id: 10f353a0-c6da-44ee-a9cb
Saving registrationId: APA91bFOz1lCFr1dT_s-HH-TatpF1XOIQ6GF846EMfmTjd_x-wARKy1zyEwr86UXfL9K1Xm8_PHpOKVuxmUXLKXHVKurXwe75EPmnBJolvS0

Saving latitude: 12.9563
Saving latitude: 12.9565
Saving latitude: 12.9567
Saving latitude: 12.9511

Saving longitude: 12.9563
Saving longitude: 12.9562
Saving longitude: 12.9563
Saving longitude: 12.912

Saving accuracyValue: 694.0
Saving accuracyValue: 611.0
Saving accuracyValue: 612.0
Saving accuracyValue: 613.0

Saving userlocaltym: 11-02-2015 11:20:25
Saving userlocaltym: 11-02-2015 11:21:26
Saving userlocaltym: 11-02-2015 11:22:25
Saving userlocaltym: 11-02-2015 11:25:25

Saving userTimezoneAsia/Calcutta
```

**But I am able to save only one set.**

```
Score Table items: Score [user_id=10f353a0-c6da-44ee-a9cb, device_model=Nexus S, api_key=testApp, gen_t=1436175254608, score=98, registrationId=APA91bFOz1lCFr1dT_s-HH-TatpF1XOIQ6GF846EMfmTjd_x-wARKy1zyEwr86UXfL9K1Xm8_PHpOKVuxmUXLKXHVKurXwe75EPmnBJolvS0, lat=12.9511, lon=12.912, accuracy=613.0, userLocalTime=11-02-2015 11:25:25, userTimezone=Asia/Calcutta]
======================End Saving values to DynamoDB===================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @readyornot's answer, I was able to solve by changing from *foreach loop* to *for loop*. So here is the code,

```
//Table name: Score
//Since array size of all parameters will be same as they are dependent on each other, 
//for eg: 5 scores has 5 latitudes & 5 longitudes etc, 
//I got the size of array and looped that many no.of times.

                Score item = null;  
                for(int i=0; i<score.length; i++)
                {
                    long gen_timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                    client = DynamoDBConfig.getAmazonDBClient();
                    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
                    item = new Score();
                    item.setGen_t(gen_timestamp);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving gen_timestamp: "+gen_timestamp);
                    item.setDevice_model(device_model);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving device_model: "+device_model);
                    item.setApi_key(api_key);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving api_key: "+api_key);
                    item.setUser_id(user_id);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving user_id: "+user_id);
                    item.setRegistrationId(registrationId);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving registrationId: "+registrationId);
                    item.setScore(score[i]);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving Score in /receiveUpdateStressScore: "+score[i]);
                    item.setLat(lat[i]);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving lat in /receiveUpdateStressScore: "+lat[i]);
                    item.setLon(lon[i]);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving lon in /receiveUpdateStressScore: "+lon[i]);
                    item.setAccuracy(accuracy[i]);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving accuracy in /receiveUpdateStressScore: "+accuracy[i]);
                    item.setUserLocalTime(userLocalTime[i]);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving userLocalTime in /receiveUpdateStressScore: "+userLocalTime[i]);
                    item.setUserTimezone(userTimezone);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+" Saving userTimezone: "+userTimezone);
                    slf4jLogger.info(i+"Items Saving: "+item);
                    mapper.save(item);  
                }
                slf4jLogger.info("Score Table items: "+item);
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the Hash key (and Range, for a composite key) on your DynamoDB Score Table? I have a feeling that you might be overwriting the same item over and over again.

If a table has a Hash key, each item must have a unique value in that column. If the table has a Hash/Range key, multiple items can have the same value in the Hash column, but their Range values must be different. More details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.PrimaryKey).

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes you are right. My table's Hashkey was gen_time (timestamp) and it was not inside the _for_ loop. So one gen_time for all the loops and hence **all the values were overwriting the same item over and over again.** Also instead of _foreach_ loop, i used _for_ loop and hence problem is solved. Thank you once again. :+1